# Django server stops immediatly after login into admin page

Tags: python, django

## Trying to login to django admin page immediately after clicking login button django server stops

New to Django trying to create a project in a virtual environment using venv. These are the following steps i did.

1.created a folder named api

2.created a virtual environment using `python -m venv vapi`

3.installed django and ran initial migrations then created super user

```
pip install django
django-admin startproject library .
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

now tried to login to django adminpage

I haven't changed anything in setting.py file

using default sqllite db

python 3.7
django-admin 3.0

Answer (score 3):

Here are the solutions on how to solve this problem.

**Attentions.** These solutions work if you have the *Django v3*. I didn't face the same problem in the case of Django v2 etc. So, please, check your Django version and if you don't have *v3*, this answer, probably, won't help you. Sorry.

1) **you can downgrade your Django version to v2+**

but I don't like this way because I prefer to use the latest versions of everything

2) **upgrade your python version to 3.8.0 and it should help** . (I solved this problem in this way)

I suggest you use something like [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) package if you have other projects that depend on your previous python version. Thanks to this package you can simply switch your python versions when you need to work on projects that require different python versions. Also, I'd like to suggest you use [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) for your projects to keep your dependencies isolated. Using a different environment is a nice practice in the case of python development.

Hope it helps.
Kind regards.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue with Python version `3.7.0`. It looks that there is already [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31092) for that. Updating Python to version `3.7.6` helped to resolve this issue for me:

```sh
# Updating version via pyenv
$ pyenv install 3.7.6
```

Creating new virtualenv using `pipenv` (remember to clear old venv if neccessary):

```sh
$ pipenv --rm
$ pipenv install --dev
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: /home/homeuser/projects/django_rest/Pipfile
Using /home/homeuser/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/bin/python3 (3.7.6) to create virtualenv…
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I have changed Django version from 3.0 to 2.2.8 its working fine now, this may be an issue in Django 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading Django to 2.2.11. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue, I think this is and issue with django 3.x.x series

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue, I think this may be issue with django 3.x.x series, once I run python manage.py runserver and then go to the admin URL server stops

Comment: I have figured out what the issue is, kindly ensure that you are using python version 3.8, also ensure that your python build matches your computer build (i.e 64 bit computer should use 64 bit python build and vice versa). I think there is a bug with python 3.7. 3.8 did the magic for me. And also in my own case I had the 32 bit version python installed too.

Answer (score 0):

django version 3.0.1 not helped. version 2.2.8 working fine.
but i find a way to access admin site without crashing the server. login to main page or your apps main page in admin site stops the server. but you can log in to urls like this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/YourAppsName/YourModelsName/

but still going to apps main page crashs the server.

Comment: Exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue:

pip uninstall django

pip install django==2.2.11

Answer (score 0):

I had the same, but when i was looking for solutions, finally, i realized that its because of my terminal, i was working on powershell instead of my virtualenv (pipenv).
when i changed into the virtualenv shell everything was ok.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a bug using django 3.0 and python versions < 3.7.5. To resolve this either use lower versions of django or update your python to higher versions i.e >= 4.7.5

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Django version to latest one django==3.1.2.
It was giving problem in version 3.0 with Python 3.7 now its working fine.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem Use Django 2.2

In the terminal type.

```
pip install django==2.2
```