# Cannot log on in Django admin page

Tags: python, django

After using `python manage.py createsuperuser` to create an administrator user in Django 3.0.2, I cannot log on in the default admin page with that user. The server will stop once I enter the correct username and password. Then I got some error messages on terminal.

```
[07/Jan/2020 09:24:22] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[07/Jan/2020 09:24:23] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1913
[07/Jan/2020 09:24:23] "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[07/Jan/2020 09:24:23] "GET /static/admin/css/login.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[07/Jan/2020 09:24:23] "GET /static/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[07/Jan/2020 09:24:23] "GET /static/admin/css/fonts.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[07/Jan/2020 09:24:23] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[07/Jan/2020 09:24:23] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[07/Jan/2020 09:24:29] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2074
[07/Jan/2020 09:24:34] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2074
[07/Jan/2020 09:24:39] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Sometimes, the server will stop even just after typing `127.0.0.1:8000/admin`, and no error messages printed.

But, default admin page ***works fine with Django 2.0.*** Currently, I am using Python 3.7 and Django 3.0.2, and my IDE is PyCharm. How to solve this problem or is it a bug with Django 3.0.2?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: If the sqlite database is not yet populated, you delete it and run migration and then create super user again.

Comment: But, it isn't any exception, so I've got no information starting with word "Traceback". And I've run migrate.

Comment: I gues you run into this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59230667/django-server-stops-immediatly-after-login-into-admin-page) Try solutions on the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59511566/12613186)